# Styling a pre tag to look like a linux terminal

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is create a `<pre>` tag that will look like a bash terminal  - black background and white letter, mono spaced font.

```css
pre.bash {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: medium ; 
  font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace;
  display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<pre class="bash">
-bash-3.2$ groups 
unixuser feegroup figroup fogroup fumgroup
</pre>
```

Comment: something like this?
DEMO: http://jsbin.com/wiheroqaka/edit?html,css,output

Comment: THis is my cheap work around <pre class="bash">
-bash-3.2$ groups &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
unixuser pbunityp pbuniprd pbarcd pbarcp pbuningp
</pre>

Comment: check this out : http://jsbin.com/dafukadaqa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: If you need an editable "fake" terminal interface, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905726/whats-the-best-way-to-simulate-a-dos-or-terminal-screen-in-a-web-page/64217301#64217301

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` to make the background a rectangle, instead of just going behind the text.

And if you want it to fill the full width of the page, instead of just the longest line, use `width: 100%;`

```css
pre.bash {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: medium ; 
  font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<pre class="bash">
-bash-3.2$ groups 
unixuser feegroup figroup fogroup fumgroup
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `display-inline`:

```css
pre.bash {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: medium ; 
  font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace;
}
```

```html
<pre class="bash">
-bash-3.2$ groups 
unixuser feegroup figroup fogroup fumgroup
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change your display from `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` :)

This is because when you set the background color to black, it is going to paint the background of the element. An element specified as `inline` will only be as large as the content of that line. By changing it to `inline-block` the element will take up the full space of that line as given by the characteristics of a block-level element. If you would like to know more, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) is a link to w3's explanation of the display property.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `display: inline;` to `display: block;`